# How to avoid Firefox overwriting visit date in history?

Tags: firefox, history, data-loss-preservation

In firefox in `Ctrl+B` library, there is history. For each webpage the history items lists name, tags, location, visit date, visit count, etc.

My problem if that I revisit a page it overwrites visit date.

Ideally I would be able to see individual visits to any page on the very same url. But that may be not possible (guessing from 'visit count').

But architecturally there should be no difficulty enabling the user to keep the very first visit date (instead of overwriting)...

So is it possible to somehow keep only (or at least) the *very first* visit date for history items (instead of overwriting it on each visit)?

Comment: @AndreaGottardi windows 7, xp and ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see the earliest visit date of a certain website (assuming it is still stored in history), I found [this solution](http://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/937585), posted on Firefox Support a year ago, that may fit your needs.

You have to use SQLite Manager extension in order to run a query that finds the earliest visit date of a website you provide.

I know it's not the best way, and it may be very long-lasting if you have to see the earliest date of even 20 websites, but it's the best I could find.

For example, to see the earliest visit to the Duckduckgo home page, you
could run this query in the SQLite Manager extension:

```sql
 SELECT url, title, visit_count,
 datetime(first_visit/1000000,'unixepoch') AS EarliestVisit,
 datetime(last_visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') AS LatestVisit
 FROM moz_places INNER JOIN
   (SELECT place_id, MIN(visit_date) AS first_visit
    FROM moz_historyvisits
    GROUP BY place_id) AS FirstVisits
   ON FirstVisits.place_id = moz_places.id
 WHERE url LIKE '%duckduckgo.com/'
 ORDER BY url
```

Comment: sqlite manager extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ ; sqlite viewer for total commander: http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/sqliteviewer.html